# Proper getmemorypool data endianness?

Tags: protocol, bitcoind, getmemorypool, api, endianness

As there are a couple endiannesses used by Bitcoin, what is the proper way to encode the `data` parameter for a `getmemorypool` [JSON API call](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)?

Answer (score 2):

The "data" is not a number (only numbers have endian issues), but the raw byte data of a valid block. You may wish to read over [BIP 22](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0022), which is the Draft-status standard detailing the getmemorypool protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the `data` response for a `getwork` call?  Because `getmemorypool` only returns `version`, `previousblockhash`, `transactions`, `coinbasevalue`, `coinbaseflags`, `time`, `mintime`, `curtime`, and `bits`.

If so, I answered that [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2907/659).

Comment: No, I'm specifically referring to getmemorypool call's `data` field, as in a whole, solved block, rather than just a block header. Maybe I shouldn't have called it "response", but a "parameter".

Comment: In that case: it's a byte-per-byte encoding in hex of the serialized block, the same way it would be serialized on disk in blk0001.dat or on the network.